CIF vs 1-Kaplan-Meier
I have a dataset where 35.3% of patients are being censored (mostly at the end of follow-up period), 52.1% have event (mostly at the beginning with few events afterwards) and 12.6% have competing event (happening uniformly during follow-up). I can't paste the dataset here unfortunately. What confusing me is that the 1-KM rate is almost the same as cumulative incidence proportion. For example, the 1-KM rate at the end of follow-up is 52.8% while CIP is 52.1% for the main event even though there are 35.3% censored patients. I know that 1-KM and CIF gives same results in case of no or limited censoring but with 35.3% censored patients the results are confusing.
Here is the code I used (the example dataset is from survival vignette which has slightly different distribution of events/censoring times though):
crdata <- data.frame(time= c(1:8, 6:8),
endpoint=factor(c(1,1,2,0,1,1,3,0,2,3,0),
labels=c("censor", "a", "b", "c")),
istate=rep("entry", 11),
id= LETTERS[1:11])

km.naive <- survfit(Surv(time, endpoint=="a") ~ 1, data = crdata)
1-summary(km.naive, times = seq(1, 8) )$surv
aj <- survfit(Surv(time, endpoint) ~ 1, data=crdata, id=id, istate=istate)
summary(aj, times = seq(1, 8) )


Side note: with competing risks, the cumulative incidence of event 1 estimates the probability of having an event 1 that precedes any event 2.  I can’t think of many situations where that is what is needed, or is easy to interpret.  Hence my heavy use of multistate models.

@FrankHarrell I am looking into time to treatment failure and discontinuation due to any reason other than lack of efficacy/progression/death is considered as competing event. Does it make sense to use competing event in this setting?

I don't think so.  Competing risk analysis does not count the outcomes that are labeled 'competing' as bad things.  See this.  Also see this.  With state transition models you can estimate probabilities of any observable event, and don't need to consider hypotheticals.

@FrankHarrell is the link to the forum you shared more for statisticians than CrossValidated?

datamethods.org is the site for methodologists to have discussions with subject matter experts, and frequent topics of discussion are hope to best design studies or measure endpoints for studies.

@FrankHarrell is datamethods.org still alive? I can't sign up to it since it requires approval of profile. I sent a request a week ago but no reply so far

I've approved all those who were waiting for approval.  We have had a problem when users are not using their google account to authenticate.  We have to have that fixed before long but for now use your google account.

@FrankHarrell thanks a lot, now I have access
